# cannot launch node of type [hector_quadrotor_teleop/quadrotor_teleop]: can't locate node [quadrotor_teleop] in package [hector_quadrotor_teleop]

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Anyone could help me out with this error??

I've followed these instructions to install the hector quadrotor packages:

```
mkdir ~/hector_quadrotor_tutorial
cd ~/hector_quadrotor_tutorial
wstool init src https://raw.github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor/hydro-devel/tutorials.rosinstall
roslaunch hector_quadrotor_demo indoor_slam_gazebo.launch
roslaunch hector_quadrotor_teleop xbox_controller.launch
```

But then I get the following error:

```
> pablo@pablo-MacBookPro:~$ roslaunch
> hector_quadrotor_teleop
> xbox_controller.launch  ... logging to
> /home/pablo/.ros/log/70bdc4c8-c6aa-11e5-a7a8-881fa120467c/roslaunch-pablo-MacBookPro-9565.log
> Checking log directory for disk usage.
> This may take awhile. Press Ctrl-C to
> interrupt Done checking log file disk
> usage. Usage is <1GB.
> 
> started roslaunch server
> http://pablo-MacBookPro:38093/
> 
> SUMMARY
> ========
> 
> PARAMETERS  * /joy/dev: /dev/input/js0
> * /quadrotor_teleop/x_axis: 5  * /quadrotor_teleop/y_axis: 4  *
> /quadrotor_teleop/yaw_axis: 1  *
> /quadrotor_teleop/z_axis: 2  *
> /rosdistro: indigo  * /rosversion:
> 1.11.16
> 
> NODES   /
>     joy (joy/joy_node)
>     quadrotor_teleop (hector_quadrotor_teleop/quadrotor_teleop)
> 
> ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
> 
> core service [/rosout] found
> process[joy-1]: started with pid
> [9583] ERROR: cannot launch node of
> type
> [hector_quadrotor_teleop/quadrotor_teleop]:
> can't locate node [quadrotor_teleop]
> in package [hector_quadrotor_teleop] [
> INFO] [1454087147.602275221]: Opened
> joystick: /dev/input/js0. deadzone_:
> 0.050000. ^C[joy-1] killing on exit shutting down processing monitor...
> ... shutting down processing monitor
> complete done
```

Thanks in advance!

p.s.: the problem is not that I haven't overlaid the correct environment (I added the "source deve/setup.bash" to my bashrc)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225377/cannot-launch-node-of-type-%5Bhector_quadrotor_teleop/quadrotor_teleop%5D:-can%27t-locate-node-%5Bquadrotor_teleop%5D-in-package-%5Bhector_quadrotor_teleop%5D/) by [PabloRodriguezPalafox](https://answers.ros.org/users/25779/pablorodriguezpalafox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-01-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-30**:
Have you remembered to actually *build* your workspace?

**Comment by [kaustubhsridhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/28990/kaustubhsridhar/) on 2017-01-09**:
@PabloRodriguezPalafox, Could you mention how you solved this. I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes! Thank you gvdhoorn, I managed to solve the problem somehow, don't know exactly how.

Thank you

---

Originally posted by [PabloRodriguezPalafox](https://answers.ros.org/users/25779/pablorodriguezpalafox/) with karma: 16 on 2016-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0